# Unit Testing Vue.js Button Press With Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code looks something like this:

```
<div v-if="day < 30" class="text-center">
  <h1>Day {{ day }} of 30 :: {{ time }}</h1>
  <a @click="advanceGame" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Next</a>
</div>

<div v-else class="text-center">
  <h1>Game Over!</h1>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do via a Mocha unit test is when the button is clicked the internal state of the data inside the component is changed. How do I do that? My data looks like this...

```
data () {
  return {
    day: 1,
    time: '7AM'
  }
}
```

Comment: The `advanceGame()` function is what should be tested, not the actual interaction that drives that function call.

Comment: @Marty okay, fair enough. How would I explicitly call that and test that? I assume I'd use e2e tests to actually click the button and test.

Comment: Does any of the information [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html) help you?

Comment: @marty I found this link the most helpful... https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-vuejs